# Express app.locals returns undefined when sent with res.send

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Im exposing lodash to every template through app.locals

```
app.locals._ = _;
```

Everything works fine on initial request when i send the template like this

```
res.render(template)
```

But when i want to update just a partial of the page and try to send the template like this

```
res.send(pug.renderFile(template))
```

lodash returns undefined

how can i solve this ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

res.render is not *just* an alias for pug.renderFile, it handles injection of the app.locals and a few other bits. If you want to do some pug rendering by hand then you'll need to manually inject the app.locals, however pug handles that.

In this instance pug.renderFile should accept a second parameter which is used as the locals object, so if you do something like `res.send(pug.renderFile(template, app.locals));` then you should be able to achieve injecting your locals into the pug template by hand as desired.

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments by Asaf Aviv, app.locals is automatically assigned to every request object, so you can also access it from `req.app.locals`.

Comment: thanks, apparently assining to app.locals bind everything to the request object so i could access the module from `req.app.locals._`

Comment: Oh yes I forgot about that, good job finding it and thanks for adding it as a comment for others!